# Unable to download grails datastore gorm 3.1.3 version

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, grails-2.4, gorm-mongodb

I'm using grails 2.4.4. When I'm upgrading [mongodb](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) plugin from 3.0.1 to latest 3.0.2, its unable to find and install one jar. Its throwing:

`| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:jar:3.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)`

My repository configuration in BuildConfig.groovy are:

```
inherits true

mavenRepo "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
mavenRepo "https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins"
grailsPlugins()
grailsHome()
grailsCentral()

mavenLocal()
//mavenCentral()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. Some how mongodb plugin was trying to pull **BUILD-SNAPSHOT** version of **grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support** which is not available in maven.

So I added its **RELEASE** version in BuildConfig dependency

`compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.3.RELEASE'`

And it worked.

Comment: But still the latest version of grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb (3.1.3.RELEASE) are not published.